# Removing Duplicates Across 3K Rows, 9 Columns

Tags: worksheet-function, vba, microsoft-excel-2013, hostname

I have an Excel 2010 table of 3,800+. I would like to identify duplicates across 6 columns, many with text, some with IP addresses and hostnames, so that accurate data is reflected. I've tried the old Remove Duplicates, conditional formatting, highlighting multiple rows with different colors using a VBA macro, combining columns then doing COUNTIFS and IF. Needless to say,with the type of data I have none of them have exactly worked. With this set of data, the goal is to reduce the list by 1,900 or so, because I know quite a lot are duplicates (as I combined an old set and new set of data, on purpose so that I can see old notes). However the latest methods only reduced by 100

I want to identify them and then be able to filter them along with the original and then be able to easily from there delete the duplicates myself by highlighting and pressing delete.

Has anyone done something like this before? I am an Excel beginner even though I have a technical background, please make any explanations newbie friendly. Would love some specific ideas to tackle this situation if anyone has any?

[image: Click here for the example]

imagine this plus 3,000 more rows. These are the exact number of columns I had,similar types of data.

I want to reduce duplicates according to A2&B2&E2&J2&L2

Thanks,

KMG

> > > > imagine this plus 3,000 more rows. These are the exact number of columns I had,similar types of data.

I want to reduce duplicates according to A2&B2&E2&J2&L2

Comment: Excel has a built-in feature to identify duplicate data.  Have you tried using it?

Comment: Hi. @Ramhound Yes, that is the first thing I"ve done

Comment: You are going to have to give us more then, "it didn't work", because I Remove Duplicates should have worked provided the values in the cell were identical. What I have done in the best is use conditional formatting, to identify duplicates, then filtering to only view the unique results.

Comment: Hi Ramhound, I can't give you the actual data, let me see if I can mock up my problem. Also, in many cells I have different sentences.

Comment: Just try an example which looks like your Data with problem

Comment: If you have different sentences then they are not duplicates.  It sounds like you want to do something more then Excel alone can do.

Comment: Really? hm. Well, I actually mocked up something, please refresh page...thank you so much for your help!

Comment: If I may reiterate, I  also combined the data in one cell from the different rows I wanted. I thought that was the right step in the direction, but at that point I was stuck as to what to do next. NOthing I did after combining the desired data  proved useful

Comment: No one in A & B is duplicate

Comment: You can use Remove Duplicates under Data Tab and select the columns you need and click my Data Has Headers it will remove the exact duplicate

Answer (score 0):

Create a new column Q for example and write the formula:
`=A2&B2&E2&J2&L2`

Concatenate the key column together and you can drag it down
Start it in the first row Data (I started with row 2)

In column R write the formula:
`=COUNTIF($Q$2:Q3800,Q2)` and drag it down

`$Q$2:Q3800` is the new column for concatenated cells

you may have more than Q3800 write the last Row in your Data but keep the `$`in `$Q$2` in that case you will have 1 for the rows without duplicate and the first row for duplicates (the others 2,3,4... depends of duplicates number)
At the end sort your data on column R Descending (4,3,2,1) in that case the duplicates will show at the beginning non duplicate at the end (1), you can delete all rows with number >1

You can copy your sheet and try this method on the copy, just in case of error the initial sheet is safe

Answer (score 0):

Try this,,

Sub RemoveDuplicate( )

Range("A1:D10").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1)

End Sub

Above is single line command. 
Or use data validation to stop Duplicates,, 
In Data validation pick Custom,, Formula, 
=Countif($A$2:$D$100,A2)=1

Or
Find Duplicate rows,, 
=if(Countifs ($A$2 :$A$100, A2, $B$2 :$B$100,b2)>1,"Duplicate "," Unique ")

Use this code,

Sub DeleteRow()

Dim lRow As Long 
Dim iCntr As String
lRow = 20 
For iCntr = lRow To 1 Step -1 
If Cells(iCntr, 1) =" Duplicate" Then 
Rows(iCntr).Delete 
End If 
Next 
End Sub